# Как исправить приход на почту?

Tags: php, sendmail, phpmailer

Приходит серверным емейлом.
**X-Mailer:PHP/7.0.32@ul14.1gb.ua**
и не всегда приходит.
а нужно что бы мой **откого@сайт.com.ua** вписывало

```
<?php

$post = (!empty($_POST)) ? true : false;

if($post){
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
    $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
    $message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']);
    $tel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["tel"]);
    $phonefull = htmlspecialchars($_POST["phone-full"]);
    $error = '';

    if(!$name){
        $error .= 'Пожалуйста введите ваше имя.<br />';
    }

    if(!$tel){
        $error .= "Пожалуйста введите телефон.<br />";
    }

    if(!$error){
        $subject ="Заявка с сайта ";
        $name_tema = "=?utf-8?b?". base64_encode($name) ."?=";
        $message ="\n\nИмя: ".$name."\n\nНомер телефона: "
            .$tel."\n\nСообщение: ".$message."\n\n";
        $mail = mail("куда@gmail.com", $subject, $message,
            "From: откого@сайт.com.ua"."Reply-To: ".$email." "." X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

        if($mail){
            echo 'OK';
        } 
    } else {
        echo '<div class="notification_error">'.$error.'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Как пример (https://habr.com/sandbox/48759/):

```
<?php 
$to  = "<mail@example.com>, " ; 
$to .= "mail2@example.com>"; 

$subject = "Заголовок письма"; 

$message = ' <p>Текст письма</p> </br> <b>1-ая строчка </b> </br><i>2-ая строчка </i> </br>';

$headers  = "Content-type: text/html; charset=windows-1251 \r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: От кого письмо <from@example.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Reply-To: reply-to@example.com\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```